# Numbering all existing equations

Tags: math-mode, equations, align

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[y_1 = ax^2 + bx + c\]
\[y_2 = \sin{x}\]
\[y_3 = \frac{1}{x}\]
\[y_4 = x^x\]
 
\end{document}
```

This renders the equations in my document like this:
[image: equations_simple]

I could number the equations by wrapping those in `align` environment, in my main document the equations are scattered all over. It would take a lot of time to find each of those and wrap those in `align`. Is there any way so that I could number all my equation in `\[....\]` without having to explicitly wrap each of those?
[image: equations_numbered]

Edit: David Carlisle's comment solved my problem

Comment: note you should never have adjacent display math, the vertical spacing is wrong, so using `align` would be better, but for your question simply use your editor to change all `\[` to `\begin{equation}` and all `\]`to `\end{equation}` This should take no time at all

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks, this worked. However both vertical spacing in `align` and adjacent display math look similar, in can you elaborate more on not using adjacent display math?

Comment: the vertical spacing between adjacent math displays is completely wrong, you get an invisible one line all white paragraph generated between each that looks a bit like vertical space but is not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(As David C. has already provided a solution to the OP's main question in a comment, this answer will focus on a claim by the OP made in a follo-up comment.)

> However both vertical spacing in `align` and adjacent display math look similar. Can you elaborate more on not using adjacent display math?

The following screenshot features four separate `equation` environments in  the left-hand column and a single `gather` environment in the right-hand column. To me at least, the results do not "look similar." In particular, the line spacing in the `gather` environment is much tighter/crisper.

[image]

It is precisely for the crisp look of the `gather` environment (which also applies to the `align` and `multline` environments) that it's preferable, typographically speaking, not to use consecutive `equation` environments.

Of course, if your document uses something like `\doublespacing`, then the  overall "look" of your document is already shot, and there's thus simply not much that can be salvaged by employing gather/align/multline environments instead of consecutive `equation` environments...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\begin{equation}y_1 = ax^2 + bx + c\end{equation}
\begin{equation}y_2 = \sin{x}\end{equation}
\begin{equation}y_3 = 1/x\end{equation}
\begin{equation}y_4 = x^x\end{equation}
 
\begin{gather}
y_1 = ax^2 + bx + c \\
y_2 = \sin{x}\\
y_3 = 1/x\\
y_4 = x^x
\end{gather}

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting solution. It makes me wonder what are the advantages and differences between the `gather`and `eqnarray`environments.

Comment: @v_manz use `align` not `eqnarray`. No new users should ever use `eqnarray`, it is broken in many ways an only kept for backwards compatability.

Comment: @v_manz The difference between `gather` and `align` (and `eqnarray`, for that matter) is that `gather` centers all of its equations.  `align` will align on the `&` signs.

Comment: One known problem with `eqnarray` is that if an equation is long enough to fill the entire line, the equation number can overprint.